# Profile page "activity" tab is broken

Tags: bug, profile-page, whitespace

It seems that the Impact space has gotten larger and the Badges space narrower. In my opinion, this looks rather uncomfortable to me as there is that really unnecessary gray space.

[image]

Also, the X-axis of the reputation graph is broken:

[image: X axis clumped together on left]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Whitespaces [seem to be the new estetic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369275/2422776). Can't say I'm a fan, but it is a consistent direction.

Comment: @Mureinik Or, you know... it could just be a bug. ;)

Comment: I could reproduce this on Brave 0.24.0, Windows 10.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on Edge 44, Win 10 (Oct 18 update).